# Adding more filter options on route groups with Laravel 4

Tags: php, rest, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using postmarkapp's inbound service to receive JSON formatted emails on a web hook.
In my case I have an EmailController that accepts an HTTP POST to store the mail.

It is setup as such:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('emails', 'EmailController');
});
```

I need the route group to not filter the POST relating to the store action on the controller.
I've tried using:

```
array('before' => 'auth', 'except' => 'post')
array('before' => 'auth', 'except' => 'store')
```

So I'm really not sure where to do this. In the filter itself maybe ? 
Also, do I use the action name or the HTTP verb when doing the exception ?

As an extra:
I'm also not entirely comfortable with just opening the route action to everybody like that. Any ideas on how to ensure that only postmarkapp posts there?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can place the POST-related route outside the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own filter and add the proper logic to it. For example:

```
Route::get('test', ['before' => 'foo']);

Route::filter('foo', function($route, $request) {

    if ($request->getClientIp() === 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
    {
            //...
    }

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST'))
    {
            //...
    }

});
```

```

You can also create filter classes for more complex filters. Read the section in http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters.